# Ember nested components in template - how to reference parent component for closure action

Tags: ember.js, handlebars.js

I have a template campaign-target.hbs defined as follows:

```
<Some campaign-target.hbs stuff removed for clarity>

{{#campaign-panel-group}}

    {{campaign-panel-wrapper
        closeOtherPanels=(action "closePanels")
        <other params removed for clarity>
    }}

    {{campaign-panel-wrapper
        closeOtherPanels=(action "closePanels")
        <other params removed for clarity>
    }}

{{/campaign-panel-group}}
```

I want the closeOtherPanels closure action to reference the action in component campaign-panel-group. With the definition above it tries to find the action in campaign-target. How do I reference the action in campaign-panel-group without needing to place the campaign-panel-wrapper references into campaign-panel-group.hbs?

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You can even yield closure actions just like other arguments. [twiddle link](https://ember-twiddle.com/c3ed352958c5af293d9c21493d54e91a?openFiles=templates.application.hbs%2C)

*templates/components/campaign-panel-group.hbs*
It should yield closure action.

```
{{yield (action 'closePanels')}}
```

*components/campaign-panel-group.js*
Define your functions

```
import Ember from 'ember';
export default Ember.Component.extend({
  actions:{
    closePanels(){
      console.log('closePanels in campaign-panel-group');
    }
  }
});
```

*application.hbs*
You can access yielded variables and pass on to `campaign-panel-wrapper` component.

```
{{#campaign-panel-group as | closePanels |  }}
        {{campaign-panel-wrapper
        closeOtherPanels=closePanels
    }}
{{/campaign-panel-group}}
```

*templates/components/campaign-panel-wrapper.hbs*
   You can use that closure action for action helper.

```
<button {{action closeOtherPanels}}>campaign-panel-wrapper</button>
{{yield}}
```

Comment: Brilliant, thank you very much for your help with this!